# How does Greg Young's Fluent Interface work?

Tags: c#, design-patterns, builder, fluent-interface, method-chaining

I'm trying to follow along this article: http://codebetter.com/gregyoung/2007/12/05/a-use-for-extension-methods/

I follow along fine up to this point:

```
Now that I have these I can decorate the Builder with extension methods like:

public static CostBuilder Cost(this Builder s)
{
    return new CostBuilder();
}
```

Where do I stick this piece of code?

EDIT: Per vlad's answer

I stuck this code where the Builder and Create class was

```
public static partial class BuilderExtensions
{
}
```

Then for any namespace that needs to have the builder added, I stuck this beneath the builder class in the same class file:

```
public static partial class BuilderExtensions
{
    public static CostBuilder Cost(this Builder s)
    {
        return new CostBuilder();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As per [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/bb383977.aspx), `Extension methods` can be defined "inside a non-nested, non-generic static class".

In this particular case, you can add it to a static `BuilderUtilities` class.

Answer (score 1):

Extension methods must be placed in static classes.

```
public static class BuilderExtensions {
    public static CostBuilder Cost(this Builder s) {
        return new CostBuilder();
    }
}
```

You can change the `public` keyword in the `BuilderExtensions` declaration to `internal` to keep the extension methods invisible to consumers of your API.